# Simple C Program Error..Can't resolve it

Tags: c, srand

I'm trying to generate random numbers in C using srand(). I want to generate numbers from 1 to 25 without duplication, So i have implemented the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
int i=0,n,a[25]={0},b[25]={0},cntr=0;
srand(time(NULL));
while(cntr!=25)
{
    n=rand()%26;
    if(n!=9)
    {
        if(a[n]!=1)
        {
            a[n]=1;
            printf("%d  ",n);
            b[i]=n;
            printf("%d\n",b[i]);
            cntr++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<25;i++)
{
    printf("%d  ",b[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Now there is a weird problem. When i print the array b inside the loop where the random number is generated it prints correct numbers. But when i print it outside the loop the first element of the array b changes to 1 and i get duplicate value of 1 in the random numbers. I would appreciate if anyone can help to find error in the program.

Here is the link to ideone where i have provided the output of the program : [Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/nUxYSZ)

Comment: A hint - name your variables in a meaningful way and the reason for silly mistakes becomes clear.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I've checked it so many times but can't find. That's why i am asking for help

Comment: I gave you a very easy way to find it - rename your variables so they have a meaning. So when I look at, lets say, `a[n]=1;` it is clear what is that array holding by its name, what is the index and what is the content.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to generate a random permutation of the integers in [0,25] except for 9.  There are more efficient ways to generate random permutations than this.

Comment: @harsh-jani You could start with a search for "random permutation algorithm".  The Fisher-Yates Shuffle is one approach.  Basically, instead of generating numbers and throwing away any duplicates until you have all the numbers that you want, generate an array containing all the numbers that you want then swap each position with a random position.

Comment: @user3553031 Thanks for suggesting something. I found  Fisher-Yates algorithm for that. :)

Comment: You forgot to include `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `a[25]` but you access any of 26 elements since `n=rand()%26;`, so declare instead

```
 int i=0,n,a[26]={0},b[26]={0},cntr=0;
```

BTW, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). A [watchpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) would have helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
there are several little oops in the posted code.
the following corrects those oops

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // srand(), rand()
#include <time.h>   // time()

int main()
{
    int i=0; // generated number counter
    int n;  // generated number
    int a[25]={0}; // tracks which numbers have been generated
    int b[25]={0}; // random array of numbers 1...25

    srand(time(NULL));

    while(i<25)  // correct loop termination
    {
        n=rand()%25+1; // yields 0...24 +1 gives 1...25

        if(a[n]!=1)
        { // then, number not previously generated
            a[n]=1;   // indicate number generated

            printf("%d  ",n); // echo number

            // save number in current location in array 'b'
            b[i]=n;
            printf("%d\n",b[i]);  // echo number again

            i++; // step offset into array 'b' (and loop counter)
        } // end if
    } // end while

    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",b[i]);
    } // end for

    return 0;
}  // end function: main
```